# Any limitation on ORDS post API data volume?

Tags: oracle, rest, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-rest-data-services

I am trying to send a POST request of huge block of JSON to ORDS but always getting 500 - Internal server error.

If I reduce the value to around 2000 the POST API works successfully. I am using a CLOB variable to handle at JSON data inside PL/SQL proc.

What could be wrong ?

```
[
    {
        "id": 1382,
        "name": "PROD_4",
        "description": "Prod_Smart_Name",
        "comments": "",
        "entity": {
            "id": 14,
            "entity_name": "data_code"
        },
        "is_active": 1,
        "is_editable": 1,
        "is_visible": 1,
        "is_used": 4,
        "version": 4,
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "guid": "99044d05f0c74df1ad10c8a6a7b035bc",
        "created_by": "swankhad",
        "created_date": "04-OCT-17 11.24.08.569000 AM",
        "last_modified_by": "runigawa",
        "last_modified_date": "25-JUN-19 09.32.54.000000 AM",
        "value": [
            "23594333089",
            "496151500740",
            "881996810051",
            "5358843633",
            "213671772739",
            "5348779195",
            "5353301001",
            "2482690600",
            "23599643375",
            "23590876041",
            "5351247103",
            "5358844706",
            "23590871124",
            "61296679111",
            "23590871127",
            "23590871128",
            "23599103268",
            "4930889250",
            "213672200260",
            "23590876040",
            "213672229060",
            "53589209680",
            "23590876043",
.....
]
}]
```

Comment: You need to look in the ORDS logs. @thatjeffsmith has written about [handling HTTP 500 errors in ORDS](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/10/preventing-500-status-codes-with-oracle-rest-data-services/) - scroll down to the section **I’m Getting 500’s but I Don’t Know Why?**

Comment: Thanks APC ! I have an exception handling block in place which would log any kind of error in a DB table as well as return the error as JSON output. But all these works when the PL/SQL procedure is hit. What if something breaks beforehand itself ?!

Comment: That's why you need to look in the ORDS logs.